# How to make canvas element expand and occupy all remaining available space without enabling scrollbars

Tags: css, html, canvas

The following code has three divs each containing, a **p** element, **canvas** element and **button**element.

How to make the canvas expand and occupy  as much as width and height as possible leaving only enought space for the **p** element at the top and **button** element at the bottom so that the webpage looks like

```
**Welcome to Canvas**
|--------------------------------|
|                                |
|  expand full width and height  |
|                                |
|                                |
|                                |
|                                |
|                                |
|                                |
|                                |
|                                |
|--------------------------------|
BUTTON
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>HELLO</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="div_parent">
      <div class="div_child0_title">
    <p>Welcome to canvas</p>
      </div>
      <div class="div_child1_canvas">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
      </div>
      <div class="div_child3_button">
    <button id="playButton" type="button">Play</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="/javascripts/vendor/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
      var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
      context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      context.strokeStyle = "green";
      context.strokeRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

css that does not work

```
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
}

.div_parent {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.div_child1_canvas {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```